# Basename isn't able to take in file names with dashes

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a bash script that needs to take in a file name, and it may be something like:

"filename - Copy.txt"

When I try to get the file name of this file, basename seems to pick up the dash as an operand and fails.

`basename: extra operand "Copy"`

I have some like this:

`echo $(basename -- $eachFile)`

Comment: As a rule of thumb: double-quote all command substitutions and variable references: `echo "$(basename -- "$eachFile")"`

Comment: The dash isn't the problem; the spaces are.

Comment: Thanks, the quotes around the variables worked.

Comment: [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) autodetects this and other common issues.

Comment: Note that `basename` writes to standard output, just like `echo` does.  It is modestly pointless to use `echo "$(basename -- "$eachFile")"` when you could perfectly well write `basename -- "$eachFile"` and you'd get the same result (unless perhaps the file name was `-e`, for example; then `basename` gives you more useful output than `echo`+`basename` does).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `echo $(basename "$eachFile")` to avoid the bash interpreter from seeing the spaces in the file name as spaces between arguments to `basename`